# dimplejs bar chart failing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, dimple.js

Functions (barplot()) works perfectly in the latest Firefox version on button click (OnClick) and Ajax request. However, in the Chrome it is failing due to common JavaScript error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined**. I am completely stuck. Any thoughts?

```
<script>
var dim = {"width":590,"height":450}; //chart container width
var data = '[{"date":"01-02-2010","cost":"9.7862"},{"date":"01-03-2010","cost":"9.915"},{"da‌​te":"01-04-2010","cost":"10.2634"},null,null,null,null,null]';
date   = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

chartutil.barplot("#chartcont",dim,data);

function barplot(id,dim,data)
{
    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    var xcord = keys[0];
    var ycord = keys[1];
    var svg = dimple.newSvg(id, dim.width, dim.height);

    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg,data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);        

    var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", xcord);
    x.addOrderRule(xcord);
    x.showGridlines = true;

    var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", ycord);
    y.showGridlines = true; 

    var s = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
    var s1 = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
    s1.lineWeight = 3;
    s1.lineMarkers = true;

    myChart.draw(1500);

}//--end function
</script>
```

Comment: At least, third line should be: var data = '[ all this text ]';

Comment: It is coming from AJAX, It just shows the data that I am passing into the method. However, you are right. I have updated that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a typo on your third line.  Try changing it to:

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Does that fix your problem?

I just made this change in a fiddle and it seems ok in Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2xS/

EDIT: With new information the problem is null values in the data array.  Here's a fiddle replicating the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2xS/6/

This can be fixed by removing nulls:

```
while (i < data.length) {
    if (data[i] === null) {
        data.pop(i);
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

See in the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2xS/5/

Comment: I came to same conclusion... Even though i still don't understand at which line error occurs

Comment: Yeah I wasn't getting the same error.  I've added an example and it works in Chrome for me.

Comment: [{"date":"01-02-2010","cost":"9.7862"},{"date":"01-03-2010","cost":"9.915"},{"date":"01-04-2010","cost":"10.2634"},null,null,null,null,null]. I am removing some of the data from the bar chart json data using delete (delete data[4]) method that append null in the json object. This is causing trouble in Chrome.